# Find the smallest prime p such that p − 1 and p + 1 both have at least three distinct prime divisors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Fun prime numbers question. How would you go about finding this other than iterating and hoping?

Comment: I think brute force is the way to go here.  I got $p_{32}=131$ doing it hastily.

Comment: Good catch @lulu yes indeed 113 will not work.

Comment: @mike, oh...no great ingenuity on my part, I just wrote some hasty code.  Good enough so that I am sure $131$ works, not so good that I am absolutely certain there isn't a smaller example.  Easy enough to check the smaller ones by hand, of course.

Comment: You can start by finding some lower bounds. Suppose $$p-1 = ap_1p_2p_3$$ and $$p+1 = bp_4p_5p_6$$ This means the minimum is $1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 5+1 = 31$, which does not work, as 32 has only one prime divisor. Since $2|(p-1)$ and $2|(p+1)$, you can assume one of the distinct prime factors is 2, and $a=1$. Then $p_1p_2+1 = bp_4p_5$ and $2p_1p_2+1$ is prime. This significantly limits the numbers to try.

Answer (score 0):

As far as an algorithmic approach, I have no idea: To the best of my knowledge there are no known fast algorithms that guarantee returning an arbitrarily large prime.

As lulu noted 131 will work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wouldn't bother for such low hanging fruit, but things would speed up iteration to find an example to test under:

- all primes greater than 3 are $6k\pm 1$ if $k$  only has divisors of 2 and 3 it's disqualified. That knocks out :$$k=2,3,4,6,8,9,12,16,18,24,27,32,\ldots$$ that only leaves $$p=29,31,41,43,59,61,67,79,83,89,101,103,113,127,131,\ldots $$  which cuts out about half of the primes up to the given answer.

then we can start to sieve based on knowing things like $29-1=2^2\cdot 7$ etc. this sieves out:$$p=29,31,41,43,59,61,67,79,83,89,101,103,113,127$$ and it confirms 131 as the least value.

Comment: in general you'll eliminate all (n-1)- almost primes containing 2 and 3)...

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the question by noting that $p-1,p,p+1$ are three consecutive integers. Since $p$ is prime and by necessity odd, $2\mid p-1$ and $2\mid p+1$, and $3$ divides one of the numbers flanking $p$, assuring that one of those numbers will be divisible by $6$. Since we are looking for the smallest possible value of $p$, assume that one of the factors of a flanking number being sought will be $5$. So one of $p-1,p+1$ will be divisible by $10$, and moreover will have an additional prime factor. Such numbers are $30,70,110,130,170,190,\dots$

This affords candidate primes $29,31,71,109,131,191,\dots$. For candidates ending in $9$, $p+1$ ends in $0$ so look at $p-1$ to see whether it has $3$ or more prime factors. In the examples given, none meet this test. For candidates ending in $1$, $p-1$ ends in $0$ so look at $p+1$ to see whether it has $3$ or more prime factors. In the examples given, $131$ passes the test.

If you want to validate the assumption that $5$ will be among the prime factors of either $p-1$ or $p+1$, assume that it is not. Then the flanking number divisible by $6$ would have to be $42,84,126\dots$ or $66,132,\dots$ or $78,\dots$ or $114,\dots$ or other possibilities, all larger than the value $131$ already identified. These possible flanking numbers admit candidate primes $41,43,83,127,67,131,79$. Of these, $41,131,79$ are immediately eliminated because they require a flanking number divisible by $5$, which we are assuming not to be the case. The others are also quickly and simply eliminated, confirming $131$ as the smallest answer.